# How to redirect outgoing links via my own website

Tags: php

How can redirect outgoing links first to my own site?
for example i got a recipe post and i got a outgoing link to another website
this link is stored in a metafield

```
$recipe_url = "https://recipes.com/applepie";
```

but in the post i dont want to href recipes.com i want
my own link like:

```
$displayed_url = "https://myownsite.com/redirect/recipe/123";
```

does someone know how to archive this in wordpress?

Comment: Can be done in several ways. Simplest way would be by creating a page template.

Comment: a page Template for the redirect ? i created a plugin but i dont know how to create this redirect

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution..

1. Create a page that you want to use as your redirect handler and get the ID of that page.
2. This goes into your theme's `functions.php` or any of your plugin file.

   ```
   function wpse405640_redirect() {
        if ( is_page(123) ) { //Assuming your page id is 123
            $redirect = isset($_GET['url']) && !empty($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : home_url('/');
            wp_redirect( $redirect );
            exit;
        }
    }
    add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse405640_redirect');
   ```

The URL structure should be `https://myownsite.com/redirect/?url=https://recipes.com/applepie`.